# Where does this resistor appear in my nodal analysis? [BJT small signal analysis]

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, bjt, small-signal, nodal-analysis

Here is my small signal circuit of a PNP common base amplifier with a resistor Rin at the emitter, Rl at the collector and a voltage source Vb at the base. Here is my large signal circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqY8z9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is my small signal equivalent.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7tHSK.png)</sup>

Normally, this is an easy nodal analysis without the emitter resistance but i'm lost with it. Since it is connected to both nodes Vx and Vy, how would that even go? I think one of the currents leaving node Vx would both go through rpi and Re is that right? So that means rpi and Re would add up? But how about for Vy? Does Re matter for Vy or its just gmVx?

Comment: Re in your diagram is actually Rin. The ground connection on Re (now Rin) is actually Vin.

Comment: @Andyaka oh wait sorry will fix that

Comment: Also Vb is a DC voltage. In the small signal equivalent this should be ground.

Comment: @LarsHankeln ohh right. Forgot about that as well

Comment: The small-signal diagram has the emitter grounded. Hence, it is not common base (as the 1st diagram). More tan that, Vin is missing.

Comment: @LvW I don't understand. Isnt it right to ground Vin since we are doing  small signal analysis? According to the problem, its a common-base amplifier. So which is wrong, my small signal equivalent circuit or the problem saying its a common base amplifier?

Comment: In your last edit you removed both Vin and Vb. Vb is a DC voltage which are shorted for small signal analysis. Vin however is your actual signal, thus not being a DC voltage. This is not shorted for small signal analysis. Notice also, that you didn't short Vb but completely removed it.

Comment: Rein, for a small signal analysis you need a signal, do you agree? How can you expect an output Vout without any input? Furthermore, as shown in the 1st diagram the base node is grounded (ac wise, for signals) and the signal is applied to the emitter node. Dont you think that for a small signal equivalent diagram for THAT circuit you must select the same nodes?